# jQuery .first-child syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

As a beginner I struggle with the jQuery syntax.
I realize that the following code is NOT selecting the first-child (the div).

My question: 
Why is the syntax wrong and how should I select the div in the previous anchor element?
Please can/will someone answer this simple questions for me or put me in in the right direction?

(I did search but I just can't find the answer.)
Manny thanks in advance!

```
function hilight(a) {
$('a').prev().first-child.css({"backgroundColor":"#ffffff","color":"#000000"}); }

<div>
<a href="#" class="bttn"><div class="bttn">Button</div></a>
<a href="#" class="image" onmouseover="hilight(this)" onmouseout="normal(this)">
    <img src="imgage.png"/>
</a></div>
```

Comment: Hint: you're passing but not using variable `a`

Comment: `:first-child`: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: Please **do not** use abbreviations on this kind of terms. `JQ` is something else, which has nothing to do with `jQuery`.

Comment: the style attribute should be 'background-color', I think

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems

```
function hilight(a) {
    //use a as a variable reference & use .children() to find the first child
    $(a).prev().children(':first-child').css({
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "color": "#000000"
    });
}
```

- [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [:first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector)

Since you are using jQuery, prefer to use jQuery event handlers instead of using inlined handlers.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pfs3A/)

- [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)
- [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Nice fiddle!! 
Of course, now I have an other question:

Why do you put the code in a function: jQuery(function ($) {...

Thank you for your very quick and interesting reply!

Comment: It seems to work also without the jQuery(function also.